# Prevent accidental dismissal of UIActionSheet on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5, uiactionsheet

I am using UIActionSheet to present two options to the user in an iPad app. The user selects one or other option and the UIActionSheetDelegate handles the rest. However, if the user accidentally taps anywhere else on the iPad screen, the UIActionSheet is automatically dismissed and neither of the two options is selected. How can I prevent the UIActionSheet from automatically dismissing, so the user is forced to select one of the two options?

Comment: is the action sheet inside a UIPopover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Action Sheet is inside a UIPopover, the workaround is to use UIPopoverDelegate to stop the popover from dismissing if the action sheet is present. Another solution would be to use a UIAlertView instead, which will not allow anything to happen except for interacting with the alert. May not be the solution for you.  I'm not aware of any other way that a UIActionSheet will just dismiss itself if you touch a different part of the screen.

Create a BOOL variable for when the action sheet is visible

```
BOOL actionSheetVisible; //in header file

//in @implementation file
-(void)displayAlert {
    actionSheetVisible = YES;
    //code to display UIAction sheet...
}

#pragma mark PopoverControllerDelegate method
-(BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popover {
    if (actionSheetVisible) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark UIAlerViewDelegate
...actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)sheet selectedObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index { ... //not sure what this method is at the moment
    actionSheetVisible = NO;
    //handle action sheet
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is inside a UIPopover in the sense that it usually comes that way automatically when using on the iPad (ie I didn't place it inside a UIPopover myself). So if I go ahead and make my class conform to UIPopoverDelegate, how do I then prevent the popover from accidentally dismissing when the screen is tapped outside of it?

Comment: See my edit, you just have to be sure to set the popoverController delegate to self/the class you're managing your UIActionSheet from

Comment: Thanks. I gave it a go. Unfortunately, popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover is not getting called. The action sheet's delegate is self, but I don't know where I would declare the delegate of the popover it's contained within. Usually you would specifically identify the delegate of your popover if you're using it. In this case, I'm not creating the popover myself, it's coming along with the action sheet, for free. How would I set its delegate?

Comment: Are you using a custom class from GitHub or something? This is an iPad question, right?

Comment: Yup, iPad. No custom classes or anything fancy. I just alloc and init a UIActionSheet in the usual way and present it using showFromRect. The iPad OS automatically creates a little popover for the action sheet.

Comment: If you're using a splitViewController, those usually get popoverControllers for free.  The detailViewController portion, or objectAtIndex:1 is the right hand (larger) side of the typical UISplitViewController. I haven't worked on iPad stuff in awhile but I remember detailViewController having a popoverController property.  Maybe that's where it's coming from. In any case, you'll have to figure out which class owns the popover to be able to set the delegate :-)

Comment: WEEEEIRRRDDDDD.  Don't just use DrawRect. That might be your issue. Create a UIPopoverController yourself, it has a method to "showFromPoint" and with "arrowDirectionUp"/down/left/right etc. Then you can set that delegate

Comment: I use showFromRect. It's the normal way to display an action sheet as a popover in iPad. Creating the popover myself and adding the action sheet to it would be much more complicated. Any good sample code you can point to for that?

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to check the documentation. I'm just not familiar with ActionSheet's showFromPoint method. If it creates a popoverController, the actionSheet itself probably will obtain a reference to the parent. I think you just init a popoverController with initWithContentViewController, set the delegate, and then presentInRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:. You'll have to offload your actionSheet methods to that viewController that the popover is displaying http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I looked up ActionSheet's documentation, it does say that on iPad, the actionSheet is displayed in a UIPopover with the arrow pointing to the specified point. No mention of how to access the popover.

Comment: Yes, it seems to use something called UIPopoverView, which is undocumented and has no delegate property. Thanks for your help anyway. I'm going to show a UIAlertView if the UIActionSheet is dismissed accidentally. It will ask the user to confirm what they want to do.

Comment: Does the actionSheet actually call a delegate method on dismissal if you tap outside the popover boundary? Maybe you can stop it there by returning NO?

Comment: It calls willDismissWithButtonIndex but you can't prevent it from dismissing. You can, however, use this to present the action sheet again! This is what I've ended up doing instead of the alert view, since alert views are ugly.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a gesture controller to the app window that does nothing? Or try adding it to the view below the sheet? Make sure to remove it when done ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw out another idea - just before you show the action sheet, add a transparent view that covers the whole screen to the window, and set view. userInteractionEnabled = NO, then remove the view when the action sheet is dismissed. [I didn't test this on iPad but have used this technique on the phone]

Comment: Unfortunately, the action sheet was still dismissed with this method.